# Azure Function config.json file does not find

Tags: c#, configuration, azure-functions

I have Azure Function project .NET Core 2.2
I added config.json file with different configuration for my functions and set "Copy always" option. It works fine for my local project.

[image]

But does not work after publish to Azure:

> The configuration file 'config.json' was not found and is not
>   optional. The physical path is 'D:\Windows\system32\config.json'.

I have use it inside function:

```
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
         .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
         .AddJsonFile("config.json")
         .Build();

    IDomainActions domainActions = new DomainActions(config);
```

why so and what is wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code, where the file is added to the Configuration? This seems a path-issue.

Comment: @Nikolaus added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was because when we start Azure Function locally the file config.json is available by `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, but published on azure portal it's `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\site\wwwroot"`

To have unified approach I found, that I can do it the following way:

```
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
             .AddJsonFile("config.json")
             .Build();
```

where `context` is input parameter:

```
    public async static Task Run(
        [QueueTrigger("domain-registation", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")]DomainForRegistration queueItem,
        ExecutionContext context,
        ILogger log)
```

Thank you Nikolaus for hint

Comment: It works in a function call, but it does not work in Startup() method that does not have the ExecutionContext. The only workaround I found for Startup() is to use hardcoded path: SetBasePath("/home/site/wwwroot/")